# "No sooner..than" passive voice construction

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

I am confused as to what the passive voice of the "No sooner.... than" construction would be. For example: **No sooner did he reach the station than the train started**

In my opinion, the answer might be " No sooner was the station reached by him, the train started"?

Comment: You forgot to include _than_ in your examples! Your version _is_ an example of the passive voice, but I don't know why anyone would ever want to say it that way.

Comment: @Kate bunting, yep sorry I forgot to add "than". I was just curious regarding the usage of passive voice in general, not that I actually wanted to use it that way. This passive construction is what had me ponder over for quite some time.

Comment: This is not passive. It is a stylistic inversion of reach: He no sooner reached the station than the train started. Same thing. When a sentence starts with certain adverbs, you can use a form like that. no sooner, no longer

Comment: Here is a list of adverbs often used in inversions: https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/inversion.html

Comment: //No sooner did he reach the station than the train started.//  Here, the verbs are 'reach' and 'start', and these are used here intransitively. We cannot make passives of intransitive verbs, but of only transitive verbs.

Comment: @RamPillai hey thanks a lot.. you cleared my doubt and confusion. So whenever I see an intransitive verb, I will be sure that there's any passive form of it.

Comment: Yes, only transitive verbs can have the voice change. E.g., study, teach, etc. are transitive, whereas walk, arrive, etc. are intransitive.  He teaches my son (AV) -> My son is taught by him(PV).   But 'She walks every evening.' CANNOT into passive voice, like ".... is walked (???).